# How to detect number in a string list and convert it into authentic number?

Tags: python, string

My concept is this, but it can't be execute by my terminal.

```
raw = ['a','1']
for i in raw:
    if i.isdigit() == True:
        raw.append(('number',int(i)))
    else:
        pass


print raw
```

The error type tells me 'tuple' object has no attribute ‘isdigit'。 What's the other way to detect a 'number string' and convert it into authentic number?

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket. `raw.append(('number',int(i)))`

Comment: Is it a good idea to mutate an iterable while iterating over it?

Comment: You also don't need the else condition since it is doing nothing.

Comment: @thefourtheye, oh my god, I've made a horrible mistake.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, exactly. What should the output be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is your parentheses on the `raw.append` line. Additionally, you'll get some odd behavior with appending to the list your iterating over. You could rebuild your list in a comprehension to avoid those:

```
raw = ['a','1']
raw = [('number', int(i)) if i.isdigit() else i for i in raw]
print raw
```

Outputs:

```
['a', ('number', 1)]
```

The comprehension can be written longhand, but you'd need to change your variable names:

```
raw = ['a', '1']
new_raw = []
for i in raw:
    if i.isdigit():  # no need for the == True here
        new_raw.append(('number', int(i)))
    else:
        new_raw.append(i)
```

Comment: it looks like the poster wanted a tuple ("number", int(i))

Comment: @mhlester I've voted your answer up yesterday. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the syntax error because there's a missing parentheses at the end of `raw.append(('number',int(i))`. Here's how I would do it:

```
raw = ['a', '1']
for i, v in enumerate(raw):
    try:
        raw[i] = int(v)
    except ValueError:
        pass  # non-numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error at line 4 where you have an extra parenthesis. Change the following

```
    raw.append(('number',int(i))
```

to

```
    raw.append('number',int(i))
```